# Vertical UICollectionView to UIButton focus in tvOS

Tags: uibutton, uicollectionview, focus, uicollectionviewcell, tvos

I have a UICollectionView that scrolls vertically with about 15 cells. Then directly below this UICollectionView I have a UIButton. I can successfully focus the UIButton, but only if I scroll down through all of the UICollectionViewCells. I am wondering if it is possible to transition focus from the first UICollectionViewCell down to the UIButton without having to scroll through all of the UICollectionView's items?

A diagram of the desired behavior:

[image]

Comment: But then how do you expect users to scroll through the rest of the cells in the collection view?

Comment: Maybe swipe to right can be used to focus the UIButton. But this behavior is not user expected

Answer (score 0):

If you really want that behavior then you can return the button in the following function,

```
override var preferredFocusEnvironments: [UIFocusEnvironment]
```

And then subclass the following function,

```
override func shouldUpdateFocus(in context: UIFocusUpdateContext) -> Bool {
```

and return false when the focus is about to go to second cell and before returning call `setNeedsFocusUpdate()` which will make system check for preferred focus element and moves the focus to the button.

Really wonder why you are after this behavior , but its doable.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I was wanting this behavior to mirror that of my iOS extension, but I ended up going a different route since I realized that this navigation style isn't the best fit for tvOS. I tried your solution, but it still didn't give me what I had in mind. Thanks for taking the time to answer though!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with canFocusAtItem to all other collectionView cells to false. 
Then directly the focus will go the UIButton.